# KVM dongle compatibility

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse

We have an Avocent Autoview 3100 KVM which we're going to upgrade soon as it's been outgrown. We're looking at a 32-port unit but I cannot find anything by Avocent which has 32 ports.
If we buy something from another manufacturer, would the Avocent USB-to-Ethernet dongles work?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem [not](https://hc.kvmgalore.com/threads/dongles-compatibility.269/) unfortunately.